# Why is Apache returning a segmentation fault when importing WeasyPrint in my flask app?

Tags: apache, flask, segmentation-fault, wsgi, weasyprint

so im working on a project and for it I need to print certain pages using weasyprint. Everything works fine on localhost, but once it is on the server it crashes.

Through some personal testing I have realized that it breaks on the import line for weasyprint, specifically a segmentation fault. Does anyone have any personal experience with this and have a solution? I have been trying for weeks and hit a dead end.
I also tried switching from python 3.6 to 3.8 but that did not work either.
Thanks